# C# Client and Android Listener

Tags: c#, android, client-server, android-4.4-kitkat

i am new to this website but have been reading alot since long.
I am little confused with this IP stuff, i am reasonable programmer but very poor at IP thing.

I want to implement C# client with Android Server[Android device moves around the world so first thing is to get its IP address].

I have written[copied] following android code from stackOverflow question and trying to use it.

```
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress.hashCode());
                        Log.i("IP", "***** IP="+ ip);
                        return ip;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Log.e("EXCPTN", ex.toString());
        }
        return null;
}
```

Question 1: It gives me some Ip lets say 142.171.13.206 , but when i check my Ip by googling 'what is my ip' from my andoird decide, i totally get new IP [120.100.78.14]. What wrong i am doing? I am running on Wifi, no edge no 3g or something.

Question 2: If i have a C# client, which android IP should i try to connect ? Becuase i am unable to connect to android server.

My C# Client code is something like this

```
    try
        {
            const int Port = 4321;
            TcpClient ourMagicClient = new TcpClient();

            //Connect to the server - change this IP address to match your server's IP!
            ourMagicClient.Connect("192.177.111.200", Port);

            //Use a NetworkStream object to send and/or receive some data
            NetworkStream ourStream = ourMagicClient.GetStream();

            //Let's set up some data!
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Plz recieve this msg!");

            //Everyone ready? Send that bad-boy!
            ourStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); //Start at the 0'th position in our string and send until the end of the string, but we can stop there...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
```

And finally here is the code for my android listener running 4.4 Kitkat

```
private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

      static final int SocketServerPORT = 4321;
      int count = 0;

      @Override
      public void run() {
       try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
          info.setText("I'm waiting here: "
            + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
             ;
         }
        });

        while (true) {
         Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
         count++;
         message += "#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()
           + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n";

         MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
           msg.setText(message);
          }
         });

         SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread = new SocketServerReplyThread(
           socket, count);
         socketServerReplyThread.run();

        }
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

     }

private class SocketServerReplyThread extends Thread {

      private Socket hostThreadSocket;
      int cnt;

      SocketServerReplyThread(Socket socket, int c) {
       hostThreadSocket = socket;
       cnt = c;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
       OutputStream outputStream;
       String msgReply = "Hello from Android, you are #" + cnt;

       try {
        outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
                 PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
                 printStream.print(msgReply);
                 printStream.close();

        message += "replayed: " + msgReply + "\n";

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
          msg.setText(message);
         }
        });

       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
       }

       MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
         msg.setText(message);
        }
       });
      }

     }
```

I have googles alot, searched this website too, but i am unable to connect C# client with Andoird server. Plz help me with the code what n where to fix. Or if you have totally different working code plz share that with me. 
Note: Thx to all those from which i have copied above code [unfortunately i dont have referece to thier websites]. Thx!